# What exactly do this variable that contains an inner class?

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

I have a doubt related to this variable that contains an inner class:

```
private final Action actionLogOut = new AbstractAction() {
    {
        putValue(Action.NAME, _("log-out"));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("logOutButton clicked !!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
};
```

My problem is that I can't understand what exactly do this line of code:

```
putValue(Action.NAME, _("log-out"));
```

Some one can help me?

Comment: Who did that???? Why name your method `_`?

Comment: `_(String str)` is probably inspired by C code, where one often use a _ function or macro to translate strings for i18n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

putValue() is a method with the 2 parameters and first parameter seems to be some sort of a constant, defined in either `outer` or `inner` class(I am assuming this since it is all Capital letters) and the second parameter

```
_("log-out")
```

is a function call to a function named ... something like this :

```
_(String arg1) // having _ as a function name is terribly a bad practice btw.
```

hence `_("log-out")` in the line `putValue(Action.NAME, _("log-out"));` will be substituted with the value that is returned from the function named `_(String arg1)`

Answer (score 4):

I guess that underscore brings your attention.

As `_` is a valid character to use in the method name, your

```
_("log-out")
```

is probably invocation of some `_(String s)` method, declared somewhere else.

Oh, and don't write methods named that way...

Comment: I think yes, infact I have it into a .properties file that is into a package inside my project, but I can't understand how to this class access to this properties file

Comment: @AndreaNobili you should provide more info, what files and what is in them.